# NiFi: Is there a way to call AWS Comprehend and connect to NiFi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

Just wondering if this is possible. In NiFi, it is possible to connect to S3 buckets.

Can you call Comprehend? Or is that capability totally beyond the pale? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no out-of-the-box Apache NiFi processors to communicate with AWS Comprehend at the moment, but there are multiple ways you can achieve this.

- `ExecuteStreamCommand` using the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html#cli-aws) -- execute shell commands that use the CLI tool to communicate with AWS
- `ExecuteScript` with the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/comprehend/AmazonComprehend.html#batchDetectDominantLanguage-com.amazonaws.services.comprehend.model.BatchDetectDominantLanguageRequest-) -- execute custom code in Groovy/Python/Ruby using the relevant AWS SDK
- `InvokeHTTP` with the [Comprehend API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_BatchDetectDominantLanguage.html) -- execute HTTP requests sending and receiving JSON content
- *CustomProcessor* with the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/comprehend/AmazonComprehend.html#batchDetectDominantLanguage-com.amazonaws.services.comprehend.model.BatchDetectDominantLanguageRequest-) -- write a custom processor using the AWS Java SDK

You can also open a feature request on the [NiFi Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) for this capability.